# Number value not displaying properly on Bar chart?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

[image]

The data of date is not displaying properly, I am using stacked now, because I want 3 values to display, the name, the date, the amount on the bar, and this is my code:

```
 Morris.Bar({
 element: 'graph2',
 data: [
 <?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from product_transaction");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $pdt=$row['product_name']."<br>".$row['trans_date'];

    $pdt_name = $row['product_name'];
    $trans_date = $row['trans_date'];
    $pdt_price = $row['product_price'];
    ?>
  {x: '<?php echo $pdt_name; ?>', y: '<?php echo $trans_date; ?>', z:   '<?php echo $pdt_price; ?>'},
    <?php
    }
    ?>
],
xkey: 'x',
ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
labels: ['Y', 'Z'],
stacked: true
});
```

why is the date not displaying the full date, only the first number? are they executing division? the format of my date is like this 07/28/2015 . what am i doing wrong?

Comment: anyway, the date is on the Y, only displaying 7?

Comment: I would check the JSON output - what is y being outputted as? Is it just 7 or the full date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per the documentation](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html), the date provided must be in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd` and you are giving `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Set your date according to the format provided in the documentation and you would be good to go.

[image]